# Can layer names in Layered PDF exported from ArcGIS for Desktop be overridden?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pdf

Does anyone know how to override the layer names output by ArcGIS, where the output layer is called Other, or .  These usually refer to things like the map border, labels and the background.

Comment: Don't think it's possible without using something after the fact to manipulate the PDF. You have to ask yourself is it really that big of a deal to go through all that trouble though?

Comment: Technically I think you are talking about a Layered PDF from ArcGIS which is not georeferenced like the GeoPDF format from Terrago (http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=2237) but in any event I too would like to see MUCH more control over what gets written to Layered PDFs

Comment: An example of an enhancement I am keen to see is "Layered PDF to have legend item in same PDF layer as map layer it is linked to" at http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000brLwAAI

Comment: According to the ESRI doocumentation exported PDFs do have georeferencing information, but since I don't have any software that will read a PDF it's a bit hard to check.

Answer (score 1):

The current answer to this appears to be "No" but there is an ArcGIS Idea called **[Exporting maps into GeoPDF format](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004Ja2IAE)** which mentions that:

> it's impossible to rename layers, once the pdf is created, all graphic
>   symbols are combined into a layer named "other1, 2, 3, etc" by
>   default, the legend and the map frame become a layer and we don't have
>   the option to rename these.

That would appear to be the best place to cast an ArcGIS Ideas vote for the functionality you seek to be added to ArcGIS for Desktop.